# Generic method only compiles with one argument

Tags: java, generics

The below code will not compile, it says that the method is not applicable for the arguments. The interesting thing is that if I remove one of the arguments (doesn't matter which) then it compiles fine.

```
public class Test1 {
    static Collection<? extends Shape> someColl = new ArrayList<Shape>();

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new Test1();
    }

    public static void Main(String[] args) {
        addShape(someColl, new Circle()); //compilation error
    }

    static <T extends Shape> void addShape(Collection<T> shapes, T shape) {
        shapes.add(shape);
    }

    abstract class Shape {

    }

    class Rect extends Shape{

    }

    class Circle extends Shape {

    }
}
```

If I remove one of the method arguments and change it to

`addShape(someColl)`

and

`static <T extends Shape> void addShape(Collection<T> shapes)`

OR change it to

`addShape(new Circle())`

and

`static <T extends Shape> void addShape(T shape)`

Then it's fine. What's happening here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `addShape(someColl, new Circle());` there are two different definitions of `T`

- `? extends Shape` from `Collection<? extends Shape> someColl`
- `Circle` from the second parameter

The other problem with that call is that `T` needs to be a concrete type for the second parameter, i.e. you can't define it as `? extends Shape shape` as would be the result when infering `T` from `Collection<? extends Shape>`.

The method being called `addXxxx` suggests you want to add the shape passed as the second parameter to the collection. That, however, won't work with a  `Collection<? extends Shape>` since the compiler can't know whether a `Circle` or any other shape type is allowed.

Assume you'd change the method to accept `Shape` as the second parameter: you could pass a `Collection<Rect>` and a `Circle` which would not fit.

Your best bet in your case would be to change the definition of `someColl` to `Collection<Shape>` since that's what you do with `ArrayList<Shape>` anyways. The compiler would then infer `T` to be `Shape` and the call should compile.

Comment: You need to do something like that: Test1 t = new Test1();
       Circle c = t.new Circle();

Comment: Or change `Circle` to static class.

Comment: Yes, `new Circle()` in the original code wouldn't compile, but I considered that somewhat out of scope of the actual question on generics. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just need to use an interface to be able to add Rects and Cicles in a same collection. If it's what you're trying to do:

```
public class Test1 {
   static Collection<Shape> someColl = new ArrayList<Shape>();

   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Test1 t = new Test1();
       Circle c = t.new Circle();
       Rect r = t.new Rect();
       addShape(someColl, c);
       addShape(someColl, r);
   }

   static boolean addShape(Collection<Shape> someColl2, Shape shape) {
       return someColl2.add(shape);
   }

   interface Shape {

   }

   abstract class AbstractShape {

   }

   class Rect extends AbstractShape implements Shape{

   }

   class Circle extends AbstractShape implements Shape {

   }
}
```